# ParallelForEach get Directories c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Here is what I've done so far, I don't know if it is the best way to realize this `Parallel.ForEach`, because sometimes it crashes and sometimes does not, can you guys please tell me what I'm doing wrong or what can I improve on this code?

Also I've got a problem with the `StopWatch` it's not showing correctly at all in my textbox, always stops after end the list of all directories....

```
private async void omplirParallel()
{
    Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
    clock.Restart();

    int contador = 0;
    DirectoryInfo nodeDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\files");
    Parallel.ForEach(nodeDir.GetDirectories(), async dir =>
    {
        foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(dir.FullName))
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbxParallel.Items.Add(s); }));
            contador++;
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
    });
    await Task.Delay(1);
    clock.Stop();
    tbTimerParallel.Text = clock.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " segons";
    tbcontadorParallel.Text = contador + " arxius";
}
```

**EDIT**

This is my ForEach without Parallel, the thing that I've tried is implement this code adapting with the ParallalelForEach

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\files"))
        {

            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {

                stopWatch.Start();
                listBox1.Items.Add(s);
                await Task.Delay(1);
                btIniciar1.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
        btIniciar1.Enabled = true;
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        textBox1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff") + (" minuts");
```

Comment: What is lbxParallel? If its not thread safe, that could be where it is crashing.

Comment: Is the listBox where I want to add all of the directories

Comment: Almost obligatory comment: Parallelizing disk IO is pretty much useless.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd don't get it..

Comment: The hard disk can only do one thing at the time so all these tasks will be waiting for the task that is doing IO to get its subfolders.

Comment: So how can I implement this ParallelForEach to do this...?

Comment: If you look up the documentation for the control (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and go to "Thread Safety" you will find it says, "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." So when you've got multiple parallel threads hammering away at `lbxParallel.Items` you're just asking for trouble. You'll need to put a `lock` around the code that is modifying the listbox. However, as was pointed out, you might want to implement a non-parallel version and benchmark them. I think you'll find the complexity is not worth it.

Comment: @CraigW. So how can I implement this on this example? Can't figure it out...

Comment: Get rid of the `Parallel.ForEach` and use a normal `foreach` loop would probably be your best bet. Failing that, look up the `lock` keyword.

Comment: The thing is that I **MUST** use `Parallel.ForEach`, so that's why I just want to know where is faster put `Parallel.ForEach` and inside a simple forEach or forEach and inside a `Parallel.ForEach` I don't know if you understand me.. I just want to compare the time of both

Comment: Perhaps if you explained why you must use `Parallel.ForEach` it would help us to help you. I put together a quick test and a non-parallel implementation runs in about half the time that yours does and produces the right results, which yours does not, probably because you've got threads spinning off `async` processes and frankly it just makes my head hurt trying to figure out what might be going on.

Comment: @CraigW. I've allready did this with a normal ForEach using AsyncAwait, as I said on my edit I wanted to adapt that code to ParallalelForeach... See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paralel, or threads may be crash if there is common objects(shared object), so you have to make sure that there is no shared object (e.g. if two of them tried to write, edit or delete the shared object it will crash, and if not it will not crash).

Comment: That's why I posted this question, becaus eI don't know if this is the best way.... It the only thing that happens on my mind